# Rolling a die and then tossing a coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

A fair 6 sided die is tossed. Let its outcome be denoted by X. Then a fair coin is tossed X times and Y denotes the number of heads in X tosses. Calculate (a)P(Y=4) ; (b)P(X=1). 
I am getting a different answer when I calculate the probability by writing the sample space, and a different answer when I use the binomial formula to calculate the probabilities. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean the joint probability?  If so, the answer is $0$.  If you meant the two probabilities, separately, what answers are you getting?

Comment: No, its not joint probability. P(Y=4) has to be calculated separately and P(X=1) has to be calculated separately - these are two different sub divisions within the same question. Let me edit the question as well.

Comment: When you do, please include the answers you have found.  Note:  Surely $P(X=1)$ is not difficult.

Comment: $Pr(Y=4)=Pr(Y=4\mid X=1)Pr(X=1)+Pr(Y=4\mid X=2)Pr(X=2)+\cdots + Pr(Y=4\mid X=6)Pr(X=6)$, each term of which I expect that you should know how to calculate.

Comment: If you look at the sample space : { (1,H), (1,T), (2,HH), (2,TT), (2,HT), (2,TH), ...... }. There are 126 such events possible. So to calculate, for instance, P(X=1), here if you count the number of favorable events, there are only two events : (1,H) and (1,T). So P(X=1) = 2/126 i.e., 1/63. What is wrong in this line of reasoning?

Comment: The elements in your sample space are *not equally likely* to occur.  Calculating probabilities by counting number of favorable outcomes in a sample space and dividing by the size of the sample space is only valid if you know that everything in the sample space is equally likely to occur.  When playing the lottery there are two possibilities, you either win or you lose, but the probability of winning the lottery is not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your events are not equi-probable.  $P(1,H)=\frac 16\times \frac 12$.  $P(2,HH)=\frac 16\times \frac 14$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate favorable cases.

Let us focus on $p(Y=4)$, since $p(X=1)$ is trivial. The only possibility for $Y$ to attain such value is for values of X in $\{4,5,6\}$ (we can ignore the other ones).

For $X=4$, all $4$ coin tosses would have to land heads for $Y$ to have value $4$. The probability of this event is $(\frac{1}{2})^4=\frac{1}{16}$. If we take into account the probability $p(x=4)$ then we have $p(Y=4|X=4)\,p(X=4)=\frac{1}{96}$.

For $X=5$, four out of five tosses would have to land heads. 5 possible combinations, each with probability $\frac{1}{32}$. Thus, $\frac{5}{32}$. Taking into account $p(X=5)$, we have the probability $p(Y=4|X=5)\,p(X=5)=\frac{5}{192}$.

Finally, for $X=6$, four out of six tosses need to land heads. 15 possible combinations, each with probability $\frac{1}{64}$. Thus, $\frac{15}{64}$. Taking into account $p(X=6)$, we have the probability $p(Y=4|X=6)\,p(X=6)=\frac{15}{384}$.

Adding up all three figures, we get $p(Y=4)=\frac{29}{384}$.